# How do I use and access the IsVisible property for a ListBoxItem in C#

Tags: user-interface, c#-4.0, listboxitem

I'm trying to access the isVisible property for the ListBoxItems in some of my ListBoxes.  The Microsoft Docs for the ListBoxItem say the IsVisible property is a Dependency Property.  After reading the document, I'm still not clear on how to implement and access that property.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I tried to create a ListBoxItem and change it's Content property thinking that that would be the text that shows up in the ListBox when I add that to it.  BTW, the ListBox is a System.Windows.Forms ListBox.  So what I have so far is:

Comment: 'ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();  item.Content = "My String to display";  myListBox.Items.Add(item);'    What displays is something other than what I want